# Conditional formatting to highlight the largest number in each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've got several rows and columns of numbers.  For each row I want to highlight the record that is the highest number or tied for the highest number **in that row**.  I know how to do this for one row, but how can I easily apply this across multiple rows?

Answer (score 5):

Apply this rule to the entire range you want to look in:

```
=A1=MAX(1:1)
```

Where A1 is the top-left cell of the range and Row 1 is the first row.

Comment: I added a little bit to my question which might invalidate your answer, sorry.

Comment: Try it.  It works for me.

Comment: If you have a header, then of course, you would use MAX(2:2).